# v-type argument in \NewDocumentCommand ignores spaces

Tags: spacing, listings, verbatim, xparse

Consider the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\NewDocumentCommand{\hey}{v}{\lstinline|#1|\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\hey|a |b

\lstinline|a |b

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is this happening? I would expect for the `v`-type argument to honor the space (as the input is "verbatim"). Or is the reason that I use `\lstinline|` inside a definition which is somehow not allowed (similar to the fact that `\verb` in a definition is forbidden)?

Comment: You can't put verbatim inside other commands: here, `ltcmd` tokenizes spaces as 'normal' spaces, which clearly confuses `listings`. Could you explain what you want to achieve, or is the question purely about the underlying ideas?

Comment: unfortunately we don't really have an accessible guide to TeX category code other than TeXbook/TeX by Topic, but for a quick workaround the so-called `DefineVerbatimToScantokens` macro should mostly work. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662557/250119

Comment: @JosephWright Actually both: I was curious, and on the other hand, I'm writing a presentation on introducing LaTeX. For code explanations, a signature as found in many CTAN manuals would be helfpul, e.g. `\verb|\author{|$\langle$\textit{author1}$\rangle$ \verb|\and| $\langle$\texit{\dots}$\rangle$\verb|}|`. For this, I defined a command taking three arguments, 'verbatim', 'italic placeholder', 'verbatim', which I can chain to get more complex commands. But to be able to use spaces (as above) would be nice.

Comment: @Gargantuar `\cs{author}\{\meta{author1} \cs{and} \meta{\dots}\}` somehow looks easier to do and read by humans than this...

Comment: @Skillmon I totally agree, but firstly, I have to manually escape the braces and still need to type them in `\ttfamily` somehow, and second of all, I would prefer the syntax highlighting from listings.

Comment: Which syntax highlighting do you expect from `\verb|\author{|`? Also `\texttt{\cs{author}\{\meta{\author1} \cs{and} \meta{\dots}\}}`. If it's about `\author` and `\and` being highlighted: Just define `\cs` accordingly. Otherwise: Instead of going inside and outside of `\lstinline`, just define an `escape inside` in `listings` and you're good to go.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you very much, almost works like a charm. One needs the fix in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43526/ since `escapeinside` does not work in `\lstinline` (which is even undocumented!).